# How can I create a list with several but not all lines from a textfile?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new here and I'd like to ask you something. I just started programming in Python and my target is to read and analyse a logfile.

The logfile has hundreds sometimes thousands of lines, and each file contains a key number. Now I want to create kinda sub-logfiles, which contains only the lines with a specific key number.

At first I created my search_strings and the sub-logfiles:

```
search_string1 = str(160000004)
file_out1 = open("outlier.txt","w")

search_string2 = str(160030003)
file_out2 = open("valid.txt","w")

search_string3 = str(150090000)
file_out3 = open("triang.txt","w")
```

Now I analyse the main logfile line-by-line and write the lines which contains my search_strings to the sub-logfiles:

```
with open ("log.txt","r") as input_file:
for line_number, line in enumerate(input_file):
    if search_string1 in line:
        file_out1.write(line)
    if search_string2 in line:
        file_out2.write(line)
    if search_string3 in line:
       file_out3.write(line)
```

The problem that I have now is that it seems that the files are not correctly written. If i print the result
, I get e.g. 289 lines that contain my search_string.
But in my sub-logfile only 253 lines are written and the last one is even not completed:

```
160000004   0.00% < fold | 4.31% outlier 
160000004   0.00% < fold | 0.00% outlier 
160
```

Could anyone please tell me where my mistake is? Thanks in advance!! =)

Comment: do you close your output files after finishing the loop?

Comment: You are using `with` to open the input file; why are you not using it to open the output files? Then the files would be closed at the end of the with block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, file IO is cached for perfomance reasons. That is, writing to file doesn't mean that data was immediately written to the file, it might still be in data buffers, waiting to be written. To ensure that everything is written, you'd need to call flush() on files, that will cause all waiting buffers to be written to disk. Also, if you're done with file (at least for now) - closing them is a good idea. Closing will also cause all buffers to be flushed automatically. So, basically you should add this code after for loop:

```
file_out1.close()
file_out2.close()
file_out3.close()
```